# Using C# WebServices, what is the Recommended way to upload records from a local database to remote one

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services, t-sql

The **Remote Central Office SQL Server 2008 database** is only available via WebServices and in need **to collect data located on various tables*** from each Sub-Office SQL Server 2008 database, on a *scheduled basis*.

What is the **"recommended way"** to prepare and upload data on the client office in order to optimize the Web Service call that will upload the data over to the Central Office?

The language used for the WebService is C#.
The Database used on both ends is SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Why do you think there's a recommended way? And, do you mean WCF services or ASMX?

Answer (score 1):

I can only presume you are transferring large data-sets across a domain boundary.

If you cannot use SQL technologies to do this for you (SSIS, Mirroring) then (depending on your volumes) you may need to create a WCF streamed service.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx

By streaming the data over the wire you will avoid out of memory errors and potential large object heap fragmentation.

Comment: Do you know at what point it is recommendable to use Streaming? I wonder the pro and cons, since I could send all the 30 tables at the same time or one at the time. The process is needed to sync data and the first time I bet will be quite larger than all the later times we run the scheduled sync.

Comment: Objects will go into the Large Object Heap if they're > 85K, this may seem small but it is for optimisation purposes. One thing that does concern me is your reasoning behing using WCF? WCF is a service orientated technology, you require data-synchronisation which SQL enterprise already provides. Have you looked into SQL Mirroring / Replication?

Comment: WCF is the only transport that my client allows to have between offices, so I am forced to use that technology. SQL databases do NOT have direct access with the Central Office